# Stochastic integral for simple process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

To motivate stochastic integration, the book I am working on start with $H$ a stochastic process that is simple :

$H_t = \sum_{i\geq 1}H_{t_{i-1}}1_{[t_{i-1}, t_i)}(t)$ where $0= t_0 < t_1 < ... $ and $t_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Then it is said that "it is natural to set : $\int_{0}^{t} H_s dW_s = \sum_{i\geq 1}H_{t_{i-1}}(W_{t\wedge t_i} - W_{t\wedge t_{i-1}})$"

Clearly, this is not at all natural for me, someone knows why it should be ?

I suppose that $W_t$ is a brownian motion and the fact we are talking about a simple stochastic process makes me think of the construction of the Lebesgue integral.

But here I don't see any measure to "weight" $H$ so the intuition one cane have in Lebesgue integral is, at least for me and until now, inaccurate here.

Also, since $H$ is a stochastic process (and depends also on $t$) this integral has nothing to do with what we know with random variable and the fact that, if $X$ is integrable, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is totally deterministic while the integral above does not remove this "random" dimension since the right hand side is clearly random

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Instead of comparing with the Lebesgue integral, try comparing that definition to the one for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment ! So after having a look at the wikipedia page, if we think at $\omega$ fixed (the best way to think of it I have found for now) the process $W_t$ can be seen as a kind of weight functions ?

Comment: One motivation that I find useful is as follows: in the deterministic setting, there are various places where controlled differential equations pop-up. These are of the form $\dot{x}_t = V(x_t) \dot{h}_t$ and naturally motivate the desire to define $\int_0^t V(x_s) dh_s$. This integral makes sense as a definition of the solution to this equation even if $h_t$ isn't differentiable; so long as $h_t$ has some regularity. Say via the notion of Riemann-Stieltjes (or more generally Young) integration where you are right to say that $h_t$ acts as a kind of weight.

Comment: We'd also like to make sense of controlled differential equations driven by random processes such as Brownian motion. However, the typical sample path of say a Brownian motion is not regular enough for this integration theory to apply sample path by sample path. This is why we mimic the definition for the process as a whole in a suitable space that allows us to leverage probabilistic cancellations to define the stochastic integral as a whole process rather than defining each sample path individually.

Comment: Wow thank you sincerely Rhys, in these two comments you answer all the questions I had about the motivations of this integral !!

Comment: @Rhys Steele: I have a lot of books on stochatic processes but I've never seen the stochastic integral described in the nice way you describe it. Besides the link you pointed to, is there a book or document that talks about it the way you did. I'm not a mathematician so it shouldn't be crazy theoretical. I do have the basics in real analysis and measure theory and stochastic processes. Thanks for nice explanation and any reference.

Comment: @markleeds This kind of motivation comes from my background in rough analysis and is in particular a common way of thinking in rough path theory. For a deeper discussion of that kind of thinking and in particular how far you can stretch deterministic integration theories for controlled differential equations you might try the first chapter of "Differential equations driven by rough paths" by Lyons, Caruana and Levy.

Comment: Wow Rhys. I never even heard of rough path theory so I'm kind of scared to even look. But atleast I have a reference ( if I ever get the courage ) and it's much appreciated. There are so many talented people on this stackexchange !!!!! It's incredible.